# Email SQLite data React Native

Tags: android, ios, react-native, expo

I need to email data from SQLite in my react native app. I want the Data from SQLite to be in the email Body

This is what I've got so far:

```
  const getSqliteData = () => {
    db.transaction(
      (tx) => {
        tx.executeSql("select * from cart", [], (_, { rows }) =>
           JSON.stringify(rows)
        );
      }
    );
  };

  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <View style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "white" }}>
        
// some other stuff

            <TouchableOpacity style={styles.buttonsend} onPress={ () => {
              sendEmail(
                '',
                '',
                'This was sent from my-app -- ' + getSqliteData,
             { cc: '' }
            ).then(() => {
                console.log('Your message was successfully sent!');
            })
            }}>
            <Text style={styles.buttontext}>Email</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
```

It doesn't throw any errors, it just doesn't return any data.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case someone still looking for the answer.

1. Declare a state `let [flatListItems, setFlatListItems] = useState([]);`
2. Pull data out of SQLite

   ```
      db.transaction((tx) => {
    tx.executeSql("select * from cart", [], (tx, results) => {
      var temp = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < results.rows.length; ++i)
        temp.push(results.rows.item(i));
      setFlatListItems(temp);
    });
   ```
3. Pass data to the email body `sendEmail('','','This was sent from my-app -- ' + JSON.stringify(flatListItems, ['name', 'qty']),{ cc: '' })`